# Expected value of a joint distribution of random variables as expectations over each of the random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Z=X\times Y$ be the joint distribution of two random variables and $h$ a function of $X$ and $Y$. My intuition is that:

$$E_Z[h(X,Y)]=E_Y[E_X[h(X,Y)]]=E_X[E_Y[h(X,Y)]]$$

My intuition seems to be supported by changing the order of integration in the continuous case:

$$E_Z[h(X,Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  h(x,y) f_{Z}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

This should be a known result but could not find it anywhere online.

Can somebody confirm or point me to a resource where I can check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Law of Total Probability.**

For continuous real-valued random variables, where the relevant pdf exist, we have, by Fubini's Therorem and the definition of conditional probability density functions:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(h(X,Y))&=\iint_{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R} h(x,y)\,f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle\\[1ex]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y)\,f_{\small X}(x)\,f_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x)\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(h(X,Y)\mid X))\end{align}$$

And also:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(h(X,Y))&=\iint_{\Bbb R^2} h(x,y)\,f_{\small X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d\langle x,y\rangle\\[1ex]&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x,y)\,f_{\small Y}(y)\,f_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(h(X,Y)\mid Y))\end{align}$$